# android load native library in another package

Tags: java, android, java-native-interface

I am adding a plugin sdk in my project. it needs to load native library in onCreate() of my application class. Like this:

```
package my.package.one;

public class LaunchApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("sdklib");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It works well.

Now I want move all sdk codes to another package. I create a new package and add a class to do sdk stuff. I write a function like this:

```
package my.package.two;

public class mySDKClass {
    public static void onCreate() {
        try {
            System.loadLibrary("sdklib");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and change application class like this:

```
package my.package.one;

import my.package.two.mySDKClass;

public class LaunchApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mySDKClass.onCreate();
    }
}
```

Then build and run, I find it report java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError. That means could not find class from this native library. but I check logs and find this:

```
03-06 18:33:30.273: D/dalvikvm(29421): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/my.package.one-2/libsdklib.so 0x418cc310
03-06 18:33:30.283: D/dalvikvm(29421): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/my.package.one-2/libsdklib.so 0x418cc310
```

seems like the lib has already been loaded.

I dont know why couldnt load native library in another package. How does system.loadLibrary() work? Is there any way to do such thing or not?

Thanks.

Comment: In which folder have you copied your plugin sdk in your project?

Comment: try removing the static modifier from your onCreate method and rather calling new mySDKClass().onCreate();

Comment: make sure you have copied your plugin sdk's `.jar` files to `project/apps/libs` folder not in `lib`

Comment: Is the exception throw from JNI, could you paste your JNI code?